# Set value of a column in INSTEAD OF INSERT

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers

I have two forms namely `frmSupplier` and `frmCustomer` that allows user to add and update Customer and Supplier information. Currently we have a two table in a SQL Server database for `Customer` and `Supplier`. We are migrating the two tables into one called `Contact` and converted the `Customer` and `Supplier` table to a view. We did this because we want that the code in our application will no longer be modified since this will take time.

I do researched and found out `INSTEAD OF INSERT` triggers.

This is the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contact]
(
    [ContactID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](20) NULL,  
    [ContactName] [varchar](52) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NULL,
    [Customer] [bit] NULL,
    [Supplier] [bit] NULL,
    [DeliveryAddr1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [DeliveryAddr2] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [DeliveryAddr3] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [DeliveryAddr4] [varchar](75) NULL, 
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastUpdated] [datetime] NULL,
    [TempID] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Contact] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ContactID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Creating view for customers:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Customer]
AS
    SELECT        
        ContactID AS CustID, Code AS CustCode, 
        ContactName AS CustName, Active, Customer, 
        DeliveryAddr1, DeliveryAddr2, DeliveryAddr3, DeliveryAddr4, 
        CreateDate, LastUpdated
    FROM            
        dbo.Contact
    WHERE        
        (Customer = 1)
GO
```

View for suppliers:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Supplier]
AS
    SELECT        
        ContactID AS SuppID, Code AS SuppCode, 
        ContactName AS SuppName, Active, 
        DeliveryAddr1, DeliveryAddr2, DeliveryAddr3, DeliveryAddr4, 
        CreateDate, LastUpdated
    FROM            
        dbo.Contact
    WHERE        
        (Supplier = 1)
```

I want that when a supplier is inserted, it will insert it to `Contact` and set `Supplier=1` or if a customer is inserted, it will set `Customer=1`.

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgNewCust 
ON dbo.Contact
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO Customer
        SELECT 
            [CustCode], [CustName], [Active],
            [DeliveryAddr1], [DeliveryAddr2], [DeliveryAddr3], [DeliveryAddr4]
        FROM 
            inserted
END
```

Where will I set the `Customer=1` or `Supplier=1`? Another question is how will I know that the newly inserted item in the `Contact` is for supplier or customer?

Values are inserting in a C# application using `INSERT INTO Customer...` for customer and `INSERT INTO Supplier...` for supplier.

Comment: Merging customers and suppliers into a single table is a bad move that you will come to regret. While they may have a few common attributes, they are different entities, with different relationships to your organization and they're going to have a lot of completely different attributes... Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have your `INSTEAD OF INSERT` triggers **on the VIEWS** - not the `Contact` table!

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgNewCust 
ON dbo.Customer      -- trigger must be on the VIEW - not the underlying table!
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN  
    -- *ALWAYS* explicitly define the list of columns you're inserting into!
    INSERT INTO Contact(Code, ContactName, Active, Customer, Supplier,
                        DeliveryAddr1, DeliveryAddr2, DeliveryAddr3, DeliveryAddr4)
        SELECT 
            CustCode, CustName, Active, 1, 0,
            DeliveryAddr1, DeliveryAddr2, DeliveryAddr3, DeliveryAddr4
        FROM 
            inserted
END
```

So here, in your trigger on the `Customer` view, you set `Customer=1, Supplier=0` - you apply the same trigger logic to the `Supplier` view and insert the data into the `Contact` table, setting  `Customer=0, Supplier=1`

Now, from your code, if you "insert" something into the `Customers` view, a row in the `dbo.Contact` table will be created, and the same happens when you "insert" into the `Supplier` view.